# How to respond to ¿Cómo estás?

Tags: saludos, conversación, vocabulario

What are the standard responses to `¿Cómo estás?`?

The only ones I know of are:

> Bien.

and

> Muy bien.

Which both are for when you are well, how do you say ok? or not so good?

Comment: This question can be hard to answer because there may be a very long list. Without thinking too much about it: mal, muy mal, regular, genial, tirando, mejor, bastante bien, fatal... depending in how you feel and the situation.

Comment: Así así will work.

Comment: Indeed, too many answer and very region dependant

Comment: Welcome to Spanish.SE!  We're glad you're here!  However, this sounds to me like a general translation question. *What are both (bien and muy bien) for?* is asking for a Spanish to English translation. *How do you say ok? or not so good?* is asking for an English to Spanish translation. I am closing the question, until it can be cleaned up or modified to be asking for more than a simple translation, which any dictionary, or google translate can provide, and is off-topic per the [FAQ](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Answer (score 3):

The exact same way you respond to "How are you?" in English: *With an answer for how you are doing.*  Some examples:

> - Bien.
> - Muy bien.
> - Muy mal.
> - Más o menos.
> - Estoy cansado.
> - Tengo hambre.
> - No sé.
> - Estoy enfermo.
> - Estoy sano como un roble.
> - Estoy feliz como un niño en una tienda de dulces.

... You get the idea.

Comment: Another one: *Será decirte que regular para no preocuparte*.

Comment: Do note that @Icarus example is sarcastic. You may use it with a close friend, but in casual conversation it won't convey the meaning you might want.

Comment: Or: *¡Pues anda que tú!*